# .bashrc not sourced in iTerm + Mac OS X

Tags: mac, bash

I am using iTerm in Mac OS X 10.6. It seems when I open iTerm, neither `.bashrc` nor `.bash_profile` is sourced. I can tell because the aliases defined in `.bashrc` are not set.  How to fix?

Comment: What's happening is `~/.bash_profile` is being invoked by bash first, which is short circuiting the instructions you have in `~/.bashrc`. 
 This problem can happen unexpectedly if a rogue program adds some instructions to your `~/.bash_profile` when previously the file didn't exist, and you had placed all your bash commands in `~/.bashrc`.  The solution is to either delete your ~/.bash_profile, or to have ~/.bash_profile source your ~/.bashrc.  This can be performed by adding the command: `source ~/.bashrc` to the end of your `~/.bash_profile` and restarting the terminal.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Bash will source EITHER .bash_profile or .bashrc, depending upon how it is called. If it is a login shell, Bash looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, or ~/.profile, in that order, and sources the first one it finds (and only that one). If it is not a login shell but is interactive (like most terminal sessions), Bash will source ~/.bashrc.

Likely, iTerm is looking for ~/.bashrc. If it's configured to start as a login shell, it will look for ~/.bash_profile. It's almost certainly an error within the config file rather than that the shell is not sourcing it.

I would put a line at the beginning of each file. At the top of ~/.bash_profile:

```
export BASH_CONF="bash_profile"
```

And at the top of ~/.bashrc:

```
export BASH_CONF="bashrc"
```

Then, open a new iTerm and type

```
$ echo $BASH_CONF
```

That should confirm the file is being sourced and you can look into the syntax of the file.

Comment: Setting a different environment variable for each source file allows for more information, that is, if more than one file is sourced, you'll know it, nost just the last one (if not the order sourced.)

Comment: This still doesn't load the .bashrc file. I had to add source ~/.bashrc to my iTerm and Terminal Preferences. btw I'm using Mac OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: I just added a .profile file and that automatically works on OS X 10.9.5 without messing in your terminal preferences.

Comment: I found out it is a login shell by going to preferences -> profiles -> general and login shell is selected under command. Valid on MacOS El Capitan and  iTerm2 3.0.14

Comment: The solution here did not work for me, but I found a solution. In the beginning, there was no bashrc and no bash_profile. The answer here proposes to create a bashrc. Instead of creating a bashrc file I created a bash_profile, and it worked. Now I need to understand why the bashrc was not executed and the bash_profile yes.

Comment: This solution is outdated, check the next post with more kudos :)

Answer (score 95):

In iTerm2, none of these solutions worked for me. I was able to get it to properly read my .bashrc file by adding the command

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

to the **Send text at start:** field in Settings/General for my iTerm profile.

[image]

Comment: What happened when you did what the accepted answer suggests? No output?

Comment: Right. I got no output, and iTerm 2 just loaded the default bash shell with none of my aliases.

Comment: That answer was broken until just now -- the second snippet was supposed to go into `~/.bashrc`. Edited it.

Comment: I use ZSH and was having the same issue. Except that none of my config file existed in the first place and had to be created. I used this answer and set the "Send text at start" however, when i restarted ZSH created it's .zsh and overwrote my file, i was able to remove the "Send text at start" and add my configs to the newly generated file. Not sure if this helps anyone

Comment: I thought this was my problem.. and then along the way realized that my home catalogue was not the folder I started out in.. so as I moved my .bash_profile to another location and I thought I was ln -s (symlinking to it from my ~ (home) catalogue, I was in fact adding a symlink in the wrong folder. Adding this here in case it helps someone else, who was going for this answer.

Comment: +1 works like a charm. May add also `source ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: For MAC OS Mojave: Preferences->Profile->General. I was looking for above option in the Preferences->General instead. This works smooth. Thanks!

Comment: Does not work when I restart iterm2.

Answer (score 36):

I just wonder do you really use Bash? May be you can use `echo $SHELL`, it is quite possible that you are using **zsh**, have you installed **on-my-zh**?

Acutually I encounter the same problem as you, I fix it by configuring **~/.zshrc** instead either **~/.bash_profile** for login shell or **~/.bashrc** for non-login shell.

Maybe you can have a try

Comment: Interesting suggestion, although this question is 3 years old and has an accepted answer.

Comment: See [this link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#Key_bindings) to also fix the key bindings like Home/Pos1 and End keys.

Answer (score 12):

On my 10.6 machine `~/.profile` is sourced. So a `source .bashrc` entry in `~/.profile` should do the job.

Comment: Worked for me on Mac OS El Capitan.

Comment: My experience says you do not want to source one .bashx file from another, they are separate for a reason :) If you are doing that, then something is wrong

Comment: @AlexanderMills The reason these files exist is because Mac ripped them straight outta Unix. There's no reason they all shouldn't be loaded for a user.

Comment: you can get circular calls if they load each other, is the problem, best way to avoid that is to flip a boolean with an env var and only load the other files if the boolean is not set.

Answer (score 9):

Easy fix.

**1.** Open your `~/.zshrc` file

**2.** Add the following line at the end of the file.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Brilliant! That did it for me. It never occurred to me that zsh was getting in the way after I installed Oh-my-zh.

Comment: Brilliant! None of the other solutions above worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

On my 10.9 machine ~/.bash_profile is sourced. So a source .bashrc entry in ~/.bash_profile should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Put your alias definitions in the bash profile file, you have to create the file but it will be sourced automatically.  I create a separate file called alias.configuration and source it in .bash_profile just because I have another user defined and want to have the same alias set.

Comment: Actually neither `.bashrc` nor `.bash_profile` are sourced.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
set -x
```

to the beginning of `/etc/profile`. This gives you a line-by-line account of everything that gets executed when `bash` starts up, including files sourced from within `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, etc. It's a bit daunting if you don't understand `bash` scripting very well, but you may be able to see if there is an error in a start-up file, and the output will be useful for someone proficient in `bash` to help you locate your problem.

You can remove the `set -x` line when you're finished troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

On 10.10 and iTerm2 2.0, customized profile

- .bash_rc should work.
- .bash_profile, try "/bin/bash --login" instead of "/bin/bash"

Comment: I voted up this answer because it seems to be the only one acknowledging that in OS X,at some point, bash would source ".bash_rc" instead of ".bashrc" .  I only came here because I was trying to find out why (and I still don't know).

Answer (score 1):

Since iTerm2 has "Login Shell" under Preference > Profiles > General > Command, it will look for `~/.bash_profile` before `~/.bashrc`.

You need to add this to `~/bash_profile`:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In iTerm2, ensure you're using "login shell" instead of a custom command including "login", which doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: What does iTerm2 command actually do?

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change and iTerm will source bashrc

iTerm > Preferences > General > [x] Command: /bin/bash

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be fixed by adding below line into /etc/bashrc

> [ -r "$HOME/.bashrc" ] && . "$HOME/.bashrc"

Answer (score -1):

I combined couple solutions together to work it like expected.

`.bash_profile` source and run on zsh.

`Preferences -> Profiles -> General` .

Select Command under Command .
And add in the text box `/bin/bash --login` .

Then in .bash_profile add line
`/bin/zsh --login`

That's it.

Comment: (1) What? (2) If you are having `bash` always run `zsh`, that is not what anybody expects.

Comment: If I set /bin/bash --login, it doesn't provide any features of zsh. Then If I change it to loginshell in preference, it doesn't read .bash_profile.
Everytime I have to run `source ~/.bash_profile` manually.
@Scott After doing the above things, I have zsh in the required way.

Comment: (1) My point is that `zsh` might be what *you **desire**,* but it is not *required* or asked for by this question, which is tagged [bash] and doesn’t say anything about `zsh`.  (2) If you define aliases and shell functions and set variables (without exporting them) in your `.bashrc` and/or `.bash_profile`, are they available to you in your `zsh` shell?