# aliases for terminal commands not loading on session start

Tags: macos, bash, mac, zsh

my `~/.bashrc` and `~/.zshrc` both files have following aliases

```
# exa to ls
alias l='exa'
alias la='exa -a'
alias ll='exa -lah'
alias ls='exa --grid --color=auto --icons'

# bat alias to cat
alias cat='bat'
```

My default shell is zsh-shell in [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/). Whenever I fire iTerm2 the aliases don't apply and I have `source ~/.bashrc` to make them work. How can I make them default and force them to load on session start?

Comment: Looks to be a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/320065/bashrc-not-sourced-in-iterm-mac-os-x

Comment: @Randomhero thanks didn’t get that in search box recommendation or google