# .bashrc is not sourced when open new tab in Terminal.app

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, bashrc

When I opened new tab in Terminal.app with `cmd + T`, .bashrc is not sourced automatically.
I had to manually run the source command.
Could you please tell me why this is?

#### environment

- macOS Monterey 12.5
- device: Mac Studio（2022）
- zsh or bash: bash

Comment: See if [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/320068/8672) applies to your case. If it doesn't, look also at the other answers. Let me know if one of them helps.

Comment: Terminal starts new shells as login shells, so they source ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, or ~/.profile (whichever exists) instead of ~/.bashrc. Many people put something like `[ -f ~/.bashrc ] && . ~/.bashrc` in their ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.bashrc not sourced in iTerm + Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/320065/bashrc-not-sourced-in-iterm-mac-os-x)

Comment: Please post the terminal configuration, so that we see how (i.e. with which options) bash is invoked. Not every bash invocation results in processing of .bashrc. You may read the section _INVOCATION_ in the bash man page.